# динамический UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, uitableview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать динамический UITableViewCell в Swift мне нужно чтоб высота cell менялась относительно информации которая туда попадает

вот код
import UIKit

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var logoImg: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLable: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img3: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        likeLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        img1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img1.layer.masksToBounds = true
        img1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        img2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img2.layer.masksToBounds = true
        img2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        img3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img3.layer.masksToBounds = true
        img3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image: это если использовать код который вы дали]
[image: а это если его неипользовать]

Comment: 1 случай если использовать .  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension .                а второй случай без него

Comment: нужно было еще последний элемент в cell привязать к низу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во viewDidLoad'е TableViewController'а  добавьте:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: это невстает  мой код, точнее встает но неправильно

Comment: Почему неправильно, что не так?

Comment: ну у меня в каждом cell есть лого имя  текст и картинка а когда прописываешь туда то что вы написали выводит только лого и имя @RedHairOnMyHead

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста я обновил свой вопрос добавил скрины @RedHairOnMyHead

Comment: Странно. Попробуйте тогда переопределить в клсае вашей TableView `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return UITableViewAutomaticDimension } `.

Comment: та же история что и с предыдущим кодом, может еще скрин самого построения cell скинуть? @RedHairOnMyHead